# Incremental filtering of list in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, list, filter

I am working on a project that requires me to filter through a long list of contacts by name based on a query entered by the user. The user can enter and delete characters while I am still filtering the list. For example, I might have a list containing 5000 contacts:

```
FirstName1  LastName1
FirstName2  LastName2
...
FirstName5000 LastName5000
```

The user has a form where he/she can enter search criteria and the list should shrink to show only those contacts that meet the search criteria. Here is the problem I have, if the user enters say

```
J
```

I should filter the list and only show the contacts whose first name OR last name start with 'J'. However, the user might then enter another character or delete characters, in which case I need to restart the filtering of the list. My issue of course is that I want to do this in an efficient way and not wait until the filtering is done with the letter 'J' before I start filtering with a new criteria. Any ideas/recommendations?

Comment: What is your ui (mobile or web)?

Comment: you could essentially use tasks which update a queue of already filtered results, and then just refine based on those (while your "primary searcher" only places new ones in the queue based on the latest query)

Comment: @ShlomiHaver It's mobile. Android

Comment: I think you are looking for auto-suggest, and I believe [Trie](https://www.toptal.com/java/the-trie-a-neglected-data-structure) is the best data structure to implement the feature.

Comment: so whats the problem? why not just search on a background thread and update UI as soon as it finished? You could interrupt the background task ans start new one as soon as input was changed. You could try to cache search-results to use for further searches, if you think the "naive" search would be too slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid launching too many queries which should help to be more scalable, I would suggest to implement a mechanism that waits a given amount of time before launching the query. Anytime the user modifies the content of the field during this time frame, it will abort the previous query and will schedule a new query.

Something like that:

**Code that creates the Timer and schedule the task:**

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
// Schedule my task to be executed in 200 milliseconds
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Launch my query here
    }
}, 200L);
```

**Code to cancel the previous scheduled task:** (to be launched any time the user modifies something)

```
// Cancel the previous timer which will also abort the scheduled task
timer.cancel();
// Create a new timer
timer = new Timer();
// Re-schedule the task
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Launch my query here
    }
}, 200L);
```

It can also be done with a `ScheduledExecutorService` as next:

**Code that creates the `ScheduledExecutorService` and schedule the task:**

```
// Create the ScheduledExecutorService
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
// Submit the task to be executed in 200 milliseconds
ScheduledFuture<?> future = executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Launch my query here
    }
}, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

**Code to cancel the previous scheduled task:** (to be launched any time the user modifies something)

```
// Cancel the task which will interrupt the thread that was executing the 
// task if any
future.cancel(true);
// Re-submit the task
future = executor.schedule(new Callable<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
        ...
        // Check regularly in your code if the thread has been
        // interrupted and if so throws an exception to stop
        // the task immediately 
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            throw new InterruptedException("Thread interrupted");
        }
        ...
    }
}, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

**NB:** Those code snippets are only meant to show the idea, they are not meant to be perfect

Comment: down-vote because both methods wait 1 second(huge for UI) AND don't stop currently executing task. Huge problem in second method, since you declared the executor as single Threaded: following query will wait for the previous

Comment: @JohnnyAW thx for giving the reason of the down vote. 1. Those code snippets are only meant to show the idea nothing more only the OP can decide what is the best form him so 1 sec is only a random value I could have put 400 ms or whatever you want, the main idea of the answer would still be the same. 2. I cancel the task is the best you can do as you cannot stop a task, you can only check if it has been interrupted in the implementation of the task and interrupt the task if so. 3. As we have one field, we only need one thread as we clearly not want to execute several queries in parralel

Comment: 1: why do you even use delay? everything above 100-200 ms causes user to experience input-lag. 2: why didn't you show how to check if the task was canceled? 3: I think you didn't get the huge problem in the second method: if you don't check for cancellation, your following queries will wait for the first query to complete the search and that is exactly what OP wants to avoid! You don't need 2 Threads, but you have to check for cancelation

Comment: 1. I explained why "To avoid launching too many queries" 2. Because it is another question, the OP only asks for ideas/recommendations not for a full functional solution, it is what I do here 3. Yes I do but same answer as #2. Anyway I don't want to go into an infinite debate with you as I feel that it is useless, If you have a better answer just post it instead of criticizing other people's answers it would be much more productive for everybody, thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

ok, so basically you need to run your query on a background thread and cancel a currently running query if the user changes the input and start a new one.
first we need a task class, that will wrap your query:

```
class CancelableTask implements Callable<Void> {
    //need this to know, if the task was canceled
    private Future<Void> myFuture;


    public void setMyFuture(Future<Void> myFuture) {
        this.myFuture = myFuture;
    }


    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        //we run a loop until the query is finished or task was canceled
        while (!this.myFuture.isCancelled() && !myQuery.isFinished()) {
            //the step should be small enough to fast detect task cancellation but big enough to avoid too much overhead
            myQuery.performQueryStep();
        }
        if(!this.myFuture.isCancelled()){
            //query is finished and task wasn't canceled, so we should update UI now
            updateUIOnUIThread(myQuery.result());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

now you need to create `ExecutorService` somewhere in your activity:

```
//1 Thread should be enough, you could use 2 Threads if your query-step is quite long and you want to start the following query faster
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

now we can use `executor` to run the tasks. This code should be called as soon as user changed the input. It should be called on the UI-Thread to avoid problems with setting `currentTaskFuture`:

```
//check if need to cancel the currentTask
if(currentTaskFuture != null && !currentTaskFuture.isDone()){
    currentTaskFuture.cancel(false);
}

CancelableTask task = new CancelableTask();

//submit the task
Future<Void> future = executor.submit(task);
task.setMyFuture(future);
//set current task's future so we can cancel it if needed
currentTaskFuture = future;
```